# Effective way of iterating multiplication modulo p

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to compute discrete logarithms modulo p (in a naive way). I have three approaches

```
LogMod1[a_, b_, p_] := Block[{j = 0},
   While[PowerMod[a, j, p] != b && j < p, j++];
   j];
LogMod2[a_, b_, p_] := Block[{j = 0, aa = 1},
   While[aa != b && j < p, j++; aa = Mod[a aa, p]];
   j];
LogMod3[a_, b_, p_] := Block[{j = 0},
   NestWhile[(j++; Mod[a #, p]) &, 1, (# != b) &, 1, p];
   j];
```

all of which roughly give the same performance

```
p = NextPrime[10^5]; a = PrimitiveRoot[p]; b = PowerMod[a, -1, p];
{Timing[LogMod1[a, b, p]], Timing[LogMod2[a, b, p]], 
 Timing[LogMod3[a, b, p]]}

{{0.094508, 100001}, {0.116498, 100001}, {0.144977, 100001}}
```

Interestingly, the first approach is the fastest, although the loop starts from scratch in every round.
If I do the same in another scripted language, like python, all of this will be **much** faster. Am I doing something wrong?

PS: I know that the internal command `MultiplicativeOrder[a, p, {b}]` will do it about 10 times faster, but I'd like to understand why my approach is so slow. Also, I know that there are better algorithms for solving DLP, but again, this is not my question.